# PHP: Write File from gunzip

Tags: php

I'm getting a gzipped File from an FTP Server that contains an xml. I want to gunzip it und write the xml as a file.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
ftp_get($ftpCon, __DIR__."/../files/data.gz", $val, FTP_BINARY);

$srcName = __DIR__."/../files/data.gz";
$dstName = __DIR__."/../files/stuff.xml";
$command = 'gunzip -c '.$srcName.' > '.$dstName;
$escapedCommand = escapeshellcmd($command);

system($escapedCommand);
```

But the XML File will be printed out on the console and not written into a file. How can I write the data from the zipped file into an XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your use of `escapeshellcmd`. If you [look at this example](https://ideone.com/fHmYST), you'll see that your escaped command looks like this:

```
gunzip -c from/data.gz \> to/stuff.xml
```

But you don't want the `>` to be escaped. Since you have full control over the rest of the command, try escaping only the filenames (you don't have to if they're hard-coded like in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Use the zlib extension:

- [zlib wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php)
- [gzopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php)

Comment: This should really have been a comment as it is not actually an answer.

Comment: I disagree. The user notes on the PHP docs contain ready-to-use code. He is just 2 clicks, some scrolling and a copy-paste away from a ready-to-use function.